# How do I integrate PHP with a 3d environment?

Tags: php, html, web, 3d

I have built a website using php and simple HTML/CSS for a client. In its simplest form : The website allows users to upload pictures and view them in a virtual art gallery. Basically I just placed images against a background image that looks like a art gallery wall.

The client wants a 3d website now, where the user can "walk through rooms and view pictures on walls, etc."

I'm wondering what's the best way to create a 3d environment that will allow me to use php to dynamically change the layout of the walls. I have been thinking of using html5 canvas.

I'm open to pretty much anything. Thanks!

Comment: Would that be a 3D website with red and green glasses, active shutters, or the real deal with polarised light?

Comment: Ah sorry. I mean a virtual 3d website. Like a video game where you can use the keyboard to move around. Basically a 2d rendition of a 3d world

Comment: Just kidding. ;-) I think you need to do very little in PHP. If you need to create a 3D room, you would probably do this on the client itself, using a HTML5 canvas or Flash or Silverlight. The server will just serve up the images. It may do a little more, because you may need some textures for the walls and maybe a room layout, but I think you won't be rendering the actual 3D image on the server.

Comment: Are those the only/best options? Everyone is against flash... So should I do HTML5?

Comment: Thanks. Off to learning animation with html5!

Comment: HTML5 isn't supported by far by all browsers, and real-time drawing of a 3D space will consume some processor power. I don't have much experience in 3D development inside browsers (else I would have put these thoughts in an real answer), but I can guarantee that it's a long step from pictures on a background to a real 3D space which you can walk through, even if you settle for Wolvenstein quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL#Developer_libraries), [Adobe Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash)/[Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex), [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight) or [Java applets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) for that.

For all approaches, you likely will have a "loader program" (or "engine") which then fetches the room description via RPC from your PHP-based backend, along with image URI and other stuff you need. This way, there is no need to change your program again just for updating the rooms or images.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Reading up on it all now.